# Can we migrate on-prem standalone apps to Runtime Fabric with Self-managed kubernetes on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, mule4, anypoint-rtf

I want to migrate Mule applications deployed on Mule standalone (on-Premise) to Anypoint Runtime Fabric (RTF) Self managed Kubernetes on AWS, but I could not find any document on this.

Any ideas or any document available on this please share it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mule applications run exactly the same on-prem, on [CloudHub](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub) or in [Anypoint Runtime Fabric](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-fabric/1.8/). It is only if your applications make assumptions about their environment that you are going to need to make adjustments. For example any access to the filesystem (reading a file from some directory) or some network access that is not replicated to the Kubernetes cluster. A common mistake is when developers use Windows as the development environment and are not aware that the execution in a container environment will be different. You may not be aware of those assumptions. Just test the application and see if there are any issues. It is possible it will run fine.

The one exception is if the applications share configurations and/or libraries through domains. Since applications in Runtime Fabric are self isolated, domains are not supported. You need to include the configurations into each separate applications. For example you can not have an HTTP Listener config where several applications share the same TCP Port to listen to incoming requests. That should be replaced by using [Runtime Fabric inbound configurations](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-fabric/1.8/enable-inbound-traffic-self).

About the deployment, when you deploy to a new deployment model, it is considered a completely new application, with no relationship to the previous one. There is no "migration" of deployments. You can deploy using Runtime Manager or Maven. See the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-fabric/1.8/deploy-index). Note that the documentation states that to deploy with Maven you [first must publish](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-fabric/1.8/deploy-maven-4.x#prerequisites) the application to Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a requirement where 50 plus applications deployed on Standalone mule runtime (on-premise) and wanted to migrate all these applications to RTF Self managed kubernetes on AWS. Is there a way I can follow to migrate all on-prem apps to RTF? Any link or document or steps to follow would be great help.

Comment: Are you asking about how to migrate applications in the sense of changes to the source project needed or the about procedure to redeploy application these applications to RTF?

Comment: About redeploying on-prem applications to RTF

Comment: updated my answer with domain clarifications and deployment information.

Comment: Thanks @aled for the information. I have gone through the links you shared as well. I will follow them.

Comment: there is some more document i found on official MuleSoft blogs site

https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev-guides/how-to-tutorials/migrating-on-premises-standalone-apps-to-runtime-fabric/
https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-fabric/1.11/index-self-managed

may be it will help more to understand the concept

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

In general, it is an easy exercise. However, things may go a little bit complicated when you have lots of dependencies on the persistent object store. It may require slight code refactoring in the worst case scenario. If you are running on-prem in cluster mode, then you are using HazelCast which is also available in RTF.

Choosing the Self-managed Kubernetes in EKS have some extra responsibilities. If you and your team have good expertise on Kubernetes and AWS then it is a great choice. Keep in mind that the Anypoint runtime console allows at most 8 replicas for each app. However, if you are using CI/CD pipeline, you should be able to scale it more.

There is no straightforward documentation as the majority of work is related to setup your EKS and associated network, ports, ingress, etc.